# How to convert a ruby on rails app to a windows/Linux service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, windows, service

I need to convert the ruby on rails project that I start using bat files into a windows /Linux service

Answer (score 0):

Windows Batch (.bat) files and Unix Shell Scripts are different.

But if you have a Ruby on Rails Service, then the languate is Ruby and Ruby is the same on every platform which supports Ruby.

So I assume that the Windows batch scripts that you mentioned are maybe only some supportive startup or management scripts.

Those you would need to rewrite on the Unix Platform.

On Unix there are several shells available but the defacto standard for writing shell scripts is the Bourne Shell (/bin/sh). More specific on Linux Systems this is the Bourne Shell which supports Bourne Shell Synthax and offers some useful extensions.

There are many primers out how to write Unix Shell scripts. I personally think that this is a very nice scripting language. And you can see already a lot of examples on your local Unix system, because shell scripts are being used in Unix in many ways. For example as startup script for services and applications.

More I can not tell you at this moment as your request was very generic, but I hope it helps you to get an idea what to do or to ask next.

When I started O'Reilly offered some very nice books, so maybe you could / should have a look at the O'Reily Bash Cookbook: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920058304.do

Of course there are surely many other sources of information including the BASH documentation itself, here the link to the PDF of the Bash Reference Manual.
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf